# eslint rules / fasle check: if compare condition

Tags: eslint

The rules i am looking for will
**Showing error** for

```
if(!package)
```

because it is better to have

```
if(typeof(package) !== 'undefine')
```

Comment: Is science based on math? Is water wet? Is downvote means No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

had chat at [eslint page](https://gitter.im/eslint/eslint), @ljharb sorted it out for me,

> No, we don't.
>
> Jordan Harband @ljharb
>
> it might be a bug, but it's impossible to know that statically that's
>   something unit tests, not linting, has to catch. if you mean == vs
>   ===, it's because == is likely to be a bug a falsiness check is not, that's a completely valid pattern that appears all over the place, and
>   is correct.
>
> Kevin Partington @platinumazure
>
> @seeliang If you really want more specific checks, you could certainly
>   find or write a plugin with a rule that forbids general falsy checks.
>   But I don't think that will ever be added to core because it's not
>   obviously an error in most cases.